# How to check if the word is a part of the string starting from www always using regex?

Tags: sql, regex, oracle11g, pattern-matching, substr

I have a text value which has a URL as part of it in every text. How do I identify if the word technical is part of the link?

```
create table t as 
select 'Part of the technical Network Group www.technical.com/sites/' as text from dual
union select 'Technical Network Group' as text from dual;

select * from t
where regexp_like(text,'technical','i')
```

I am getting both the texts. I need just the first text. The link may differ it can be www.tech.technical as well.

Comment: `where regexp_like(text,'www\.technical','i')`? Where is the word `technical` expected to apprear? Right after `www.`?

Comment: You have a lot of questions with answers, none of which have been accepted. Did they really all not work?

Comment: If we had another text like 'www.tech.technical.com Network Group' , need that as well.

Comment: I am trying to text process, Nick. Getting stuck at the small changes I have to make to the data.

Comment: `regexp_like(txt,'www(\.[^/]+)?\.technical','i')`? Or `regexp_like(txt,'www(\.[^/]+)?\.technical\.','i')`? Should it be a part of the host, or of the whole path? Or a part of a query string, too? Maybe `regexp_like(txt,'www\.\S*technical','i')`?

Comment: It should be a part of the whole path.

Comment: So, `regexp_like(txt,'www\.\S*technical','i')` works, right?

Comment: Yes, it works, Wiktor. Thank you! :)

Comment: I did accept. But as I am a new member, I am unable to upvote!

Comment: I just reached to 16. Thanks for the detailed explanation below. Helps new users of regexp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(text,'www\.\S*technical','i')
```

Or, if you also want to consider the URL can start with `http` or `https`,

```
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(text,'(https?://|www\.)\S*technical','i')
```

**Details**

- `www\.` - a `www.` substring
- `\S*` - 0+ chars other than whitespace
- `technical` - a `technical` substring.

See the [online demo](https://rextester.com/ILV80344):

```
with testdata(text) as (
      select 'Part of the technical Network Group www.technical.com/sites/'  from dual
      union
      select 'Part of the technical Network Group www.some.com/sites/technical'  from dual
      union
      select 'Technical Network Group' from dual
   )
select * from testdata where regexp_like(text,'www\.\S*technical','i')
```

Output:

[image]

See [another demo](https://rextester.com/SSO17040) with `http`/`https` support.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something to what @Wiktor suggested in the comment

```
select * from t
where regexp_like(text,'www\..*technical','i')
```

Here a sample in [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/03704/1). But you will be much better off learning Regex because the urls that you can find can be quite different.

Comment: Here, `.*` matches any 0+ chars, and you risk matching `technical` outside of a link.

Comment: I agree, but there could be also links like `http://technical.com` which also will be missed, this is way the right answer for me would be "learn your Regex"